# how do i get tableview to center 3 cells on the screen?

Tags: ios, uitableview

how can i have a UITableView, that takes up the entire screen and has 3 cells, center those 3 cells to the center of the screen instead of the top of the table.

Comment: Try setting an appropriate `contentInset` on the table view. This is a property inherited from `UIScrollView`.

Comment: I would suggest this, create a new class which is a subclass of UIView, and create a new assign .xib and assign its class to your newly created class. Your xib will have a view and a table view in it. Make this class as the delegate and datasource for your table view. Now in your main view controller create your new view and add it to you main view as a sub view. You can set autolayout constraints so that your subview will be always in the center.

Comment: @rmaddy I totally forgot about using insets. Thanks!